# Block AzureRM PowerShell Module

Tags: powershell, azure, restrictions, group-policy

Is there a way to block AzureRM PowerShell module commands from being executed by certain Azure AD users somewhere in Azure group policy? Or is there a way to do this with PowerShell tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, Azure Resource Manager PowerShell scripts use the same permissions as the Azure portal, so no, you cannot prevent a user from running a PowerShell commandlet and still let them perform the same actions on the Azure portal.   [This link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal) provides more information about managing Windows Azure Permissions